# How to make fluids come out in a local coordinates?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to make a liquid simulation with Mantaflow where the flow of the liquid respects the flow object's local rotation, so it looks like water spraying in different directions.

It looks like the options on the flow object only work for 'world' coordinates and doesn't take into account the coordinates of the object.

How do I make the water 'fire' (like a hose) into a specific direction that uses **local coordinates** instead of world ones?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you rotate the flow generator?

[image]

Comment: The real reason it didn't work for me is because I was using a uv sphere. If I had tried to use the same settings as you, particles would have flowed out of every face. The only way to get a 'directional' flow is to have a flat object like yours and change the normal velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the inflow values to be local. You can use drivers to adjust the values so that it won't be so hard to keep track of when rotating the inflow, but you will have to use global values for fluid input.